# Обновление картинки в бд

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Как обновить картинку в бд, а именно как грамотно написать запрос ?

```
INSERT INTO tovars (name) VALUES('$uploadfile')
```

name - название поле где хранится адрес картинки на сервере в виде /o/1.png
$uploadfile - содержит путь картинки которые записывается в бд.
Подскажите как мне написать запрос обновления картинки в бд. Проблема еще в том что, картинку я имею на определенной строке. То есть нужно условие where id=id
Попробовал сам

```
UPDATE `tovars` SET `name`='$uploadfile' where id=$id
```

не работает

Comment: да, только путь.

Comment: попробуйте так $sql = "UPDATE tovars SET name='" + ВАШЕ_ИМЯ_КАРТИНКИ +"' WHERE id=" + ИД_ЗАПИСИ; Если хотите через переменные, то UPDATE tovars SET name='$uploadfile' where id=$id(тут дело в том, что текстовые переменные надо экранировать)

Comment: Возможно беда как раз из-за того, что вы ставите `

Comment: @Chubatiy, проблема в условии где Where id=$id, запустил с параметром вот так UPDATE tovars SET name='$uploadfile' where id=79, картинка поменялась

Comment: У вас определена переменная $id в коде?

Comment: да, определена но в другом файле.

Comment: Так может она просто не подтягивается сюда? Перед вызовом запроса сделайте вывод переменной $id просто в консоль

Comment: попробовал вывести, получил NULL

Comment: Вот вам и объяснение. Запрос у вас написан верно. Просто не подтягивается значение переменной $id. Вот на выходе вы и получаете, что .....where id=null, а это баг

Answer (score 2):

Если вы используете стандатную библиотеку работы с Mysql - mysql_query,то

```
$sql = "UPDATE `tovars` SET `name`='".$uploadfile."' where id=".$id;
```

или

```
 $sql = "UPDATE `tovars` SET `name`='{$uploadfile}' where id='{$id}'";
```

Обратите внимание что строковые переменные в таблицу заносятся в кавычках, иначе могут вызовут ошибку SQL.
Больше об этом вы можете прочитать в официальной документации PHP [Строки](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc)

Так же советую прочитать статьи по базопасности сохранения данных без защиты (экранирование и т.д.)